# Calling block's method in template doesn't work

Tags: module, blocks, template

I'm trying to create custom admin module in Magento CE 1.9.2.4.

The module has two blocks because I thought it would be nice to move the logic parts of these views into their block files.

So the problem is I can't call methods in the block files from the templates. If I don't try to do the call the template files' HTML content is displayed normally, but if I try to do the call (as shown below) the template where the call resides doesn't show up. Probably has something to do with the exception I keep having.

```
Invalid block type: Company_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Productlist
```

What am I doing wrong? What should the block type be?

*var/log/exception.log*

```
2016-10-20T08:26:57+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Company_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Productlist' in /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('company_modulena...', Array)
#2 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('company_modulena...', 'oa_productlist')
#3 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('company_modulena...', 'oa_productlist')
#4 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#8 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#10 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/local/Company/ModuleName/controllers/Adminhtml/ModulenamebackendController.php(23): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#11 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/local/Company/ModuleName/controllers/Adminhtml/ModulenamebackendController.php(10): Company_ModuleName_Adminhtml_ModulenamebackendController->showContent()
#12 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Company_ModuleName_Adminhtml_ModulenamebackendController->indexAction()
#13 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#14 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /Users/username/Sites/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /Users/username/Sites/magento/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

And here are the files that have something to do with the module (I hope I didn't forget anything):

*app/etc/modules/Company_Modulename.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Company_Modulename>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Company_Modulename>
  </modules>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/Company/Modulename/etc/config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Company_Modulename>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Company_Modulename>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <company_modulename>
        <class>Company_Modulename_Block</class>
      </company_modulename>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <modulename>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Company_Modulename</module>
          <frontName>company_modulename</frontName>
        </args>
      </modulename>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <modulename>
          <file>modulename.xml</file>
        </modulename>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/Company/Modulename/controllers/Adminhtml/ModulenamebackendController.php*

```
class Company_Modulename_Adminhtml_ModulenamebackendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_title($this->__("Custom title"));
    $this->renderLayout();
  }
}
```

*app/code/local/Company/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Modulenamebackend.php*

```
class Company_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Modulenamebackend extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template{}
```

*app/code/local/Company/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Productlist.php*

```
class Company_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Productlist extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{
  public function myfunction()
  {
    return "Hello world";
  }
}
```

*app/code/local/Company/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Optionlist.php*

```
class Company_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Optionlist extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template{}
```

*app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/modulename.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <modulename_adminhtml_modulenamebackend_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="core/template" name="modulename" template="modulename/view.phtml">
        <block type="company_modulename/adminhtml_productlist" as="mn_productlist" name="mn_productlist" template="modulename/productlist.phtml" />
        <block type="company_modulename/adminhtml_optionlist" as="mn_optionlist" name="mn_optionlist" template="modulename/optionlist.phtml" />
      </block>
    </reference>
  </modulename_adminhtml_modulenamebackend_index>
</layout>
```

*app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/modulename/view.phtml*

```
<h2>Something</h2>
<div>
  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mn_productlist') ?>
</div>
<div>
  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mn_optionlist') ?>
</div>
```

*app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/modulename/optionlist.phtml*

```
<p>This is some content</p>
```

*app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/modulename/productlist.phtml*

```
<p>This text shows if the php on this file is commented</p>
<?php
  echo $this->myfunction();
?>
```

Comment: Change ModuleName to Modulename just

Comment: I changed the ModuleName to Modulename but it didn't solve the problem. I guess it's not a bad idea to keep only one capital letter in the modulename though.

Comment: Please Give a permissions Both Block as System -> permissions -> Blocks  company_modulename/adminhtml_productlist        and    company_modulename/adminhtml_optionlist

Comment: The modules have permission but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your `config.xml` this

```
<blocks>
  <modulename>
    <class>Company_Modulename_Block</class>
  </modulename>
</blocks>
```

should be

```
<blocks>
  <company_modulename>
    <class>Company_Modulename_Block</class>
  </company_modulename>
</blocks>
```

Comment: I did this but it didn't help. I didn't break anything either so I'll just keep it like this for now.

Comment: clear the cache when you are done

Comment: I did. Did again too. Didn't help.